# Thymleaf prints too much information on the console

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

When starting a Spring boot application with Thymeleaf, a lot of information is being displayed in the console about the version it uses, the dialects that are available and so on.

How can I make sure that this information isn't printed to the console?

This is a screenshot of the information that is being displayed:

[image: Screenshot of the console]

Comment: Can you elaborate what version of Spring Boot and what version of other dependencies you are using? Did you configure [logging of Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) in any way ?

Comment: The parent class version inherited by springboot is ”<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>“ and log setted in application.yml is:
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure: error

Comment: Can you try setting the log level for `org.thymeleaf` to `INFO` ?

Comment: It‘s cool,it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the logging level of `org.thymeleaf` to `INFO` so that this DEBUG information is no longer printed.